# Javascript Math.floor time calculcation

Tags: javascript, math

This might be a stupid question, but I am making a countdown script and I can't get the "week" countdown working. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jun 23, 2017 19:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var weeks = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 7));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = weeks + " Weeks";
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days + " Days";
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours + " Hours";
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes + " Minutes";
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds + " Seconds";
  
  
    document.getElementById("hms").innerHTML = hours + ":"
  + minutes + ":" + seconds + "";
  

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("weeks").innerHTML = "Sorry!";
  document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = "No";
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "New";
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "Possible";
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "Date";
  }
}, 1000);
```

I must be using the wrong calculation somewhere. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of distance?

Comment: *"not working"* is not a proper descriptive problem statement

Comment: What is it doing wrong ?

Comment: updated post, it shows just 0 Weeks

Comment: You've missed the end off your code so we can't see the end of that setInterval call.

Comment: But where is the problem ? A [mcve] should show the expect output too.

Comment: i still cant get it to work... `Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 7));` for weeks looked at first correct (21) but now it is decreasing every 5 minutes

Comment: Check your division value, it probably should be `1000*60*60*24*7` to match weeks unit. You are using the equivalent of 7minutes to divide. This is badly written to be fair. You should do this in the other way, seconds first.

Comment: Tried, result: 0 Weeks; Code 1: `Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 )));` Result = 7897220 weeks. Code 2: `Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 24 * 7));` Result = 0 Weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
var weeks = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 7));
```

be this

```
var weeks = Math.floor((distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)));
```

Comment: Result is 7818771 Weeks

Comment: Sorry should be a slash instead of percentage (if your day calculation works) - see edit above

Comment: Yes, works like a charm thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)